# Illegal redirect_uri message for the Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

```js
/**
 * This is an example of a basic node.js script that performs
 * the Authorization Code oAuth2 flow to authenticate against
 * the Spotify Accounts.
 *
 * For more information, read
 * https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow
 */

var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var client_id = '54564f79593549238d76cf06af0fe9fb'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'd93c7a3dadb5435ba308e61cf82e5234'; // Your secret
var redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'; // Your redirect uri

/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
var generateRandomString = function(length) {
  var text = '';
  var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
  }
  return text;
};

var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);
alert("FADFADFGADGFDAF")
  // your application requests authorization
  var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email';
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {

  // requesting access token from refresh token
  var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example of the Authorization Code flow with Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      #login, #loggedin {
        display: none;
      }
      .text-overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login">
        <h1>This is an example of the Authorization Code flow</h1>
        <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Log in with Spotify</a>
      </div>
      <div id="loggedin">
        <div id="user-profile">
        </div>
        <div id="oauth">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="obtain-new-token">Obtain new token using the refresh token</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script id="user-profile-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>Logged in as {{display_name}}</h1>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object" width="150" src="{{images.0.url}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
            <dt>Id</dt><dd>{{id}}</dd>
            <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{email}}</dd>
            <dt>Spotify URI</dt><dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Link</dt><dd><a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Profile Image</dt><dd class="clearfix"><a href="{{images.0.url}}">{{images.0.url}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{country}}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script id="oauth-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>oAuth info</h2>
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Access token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{access_token}}</dd>
        <dt>Refresh token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{refresh_token}}></dd>
      </dl>
    </script>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {

        /**
         * Obtains parameters from the hash of the URL
         * @return Object
         */
        function getHashParams() {
          var hashParams = {};
          var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
              q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
             hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
          }
          return hashParams;
        }

        var userProfileSource = document.getElementById('user-profile-template').innerHTML,
            userProfileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(userProfileSource),
            userProfilePlaceholder = document.getElementById('user-profile');

        var oauthSource = document.getElementById('oauth-template').innerHTML,
            oauthTemplate = Handlebars.compile(oauthSource),
            oauthPlaceholder = document.getElementById('oauth');

        var params = getHashParams();

        var access_token = params.access_token,
            refresh_token = params.refresh_token,
            error = params.error;

        if (error) {
          alert('There was an error during the authentication');
        } else {
          if (access_token) {
            // render oauth info
            oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
              access_token: access_token,
              refresh_token: refresh_token
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                success: function(response) {
                  userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

                  $('#login').hide();
                  $('#loggedin').show();
                }
            });
          } else {
              // render initial screen
              $('#login').show();
              $('#loggedin').hide();
          }

          document.getElementById('obtain-new-token').addEventListener('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/refresh_token',
              data: {
                'refresh_token': refresh_token
              }
            }).done(function(data) {
              access_token = data.access_token;
              oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
                access_token: access_token,
                refresh_token: refresh_token
              });
            });
          }, false);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to build an application using the Spotify API for a school project. I trying to make my way through the tutorial on the Spotify developer website. But I'm stuck on the end of the authorization guide. 
When I click on the 'login with spotify' button on the page that I serve on localhost:8888, I get the message 'illegal redirect_uri'.

I've searched the internet for possible solutions, and it seems to have something to do with the redirect_uri not being 'whitelisted'.

I've added localhost:8888, localhost:8888/callback, both with and without backslashes to my whitelist in my applications where you find your client_id and client_secret keys. This does not solve the problem.

I'm stuck on completing the tutorial. I don't know where to look for the solution.
Is there anyone that can help me, please?
btw. I'm working with Node.js

---

I continued my search for the solutions and I opened my console in my chrome browser. I get error 400 (bad request) The server responded with `statusCode 400`.
But as I look at the URL of the authorization

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=**CLIENT_…**/private%20user-read-email&redirect_uri=**REDIRECT_URI**&state=V5sC8qlArWgBf0y9....
```

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

I have changed my `client_id`, `client_secret` and `redirect_uri` on my own numbers that where given to my by Spotify itself.
I think the value of the  variable is not responding. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you share your code? That way it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: @MartinGoltweis I edited my question and add the code. You'll see it above the question. Many thank for looking in to it!

Comment: @MartinGottweis I edited my question and add the code. You'll see it above the question. Many thank for looking in to it!